# When I enlarge the page in IE7,the style does not work?

Tags: javascript, css

for example ,this is a js code: befor scrolling

```
<div style="left: auto; position: relative;">
   <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li
   </ul>
</div>
```

after scrolling

```
<div style="left: 375.6px; position: fixed; top: 0px;">
   <ul>
     <li></li>
     <li></li
   </ul>
</div>
```

then I enlarge the page 120% ,this div style does not follow it becoming 120%? I mean in IE7

Comment: Maybe it's time to code for a browser people use? http://theie7countdown.com/

Comment: @JeremyMiller he may have a restriction on which browsers he can use.

Comment: Please update your browser. IE7 is way too old and broken.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Sweet.  Then I'll code for Win 3.1.  For such questions, maybe http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ is a better fit?

Comment: Nicholas Kyriakides has a point there. Just a year ago I heard stories about a bank still using IE6 for inhouse applications.

Comment: @Bart And this last week one of our representatives was found to be using IE8.  I recommended and guided them to upgrading their 1/2 decade-old application which posed a security risk to their system (esp since they hadn't upgraded).  I bet that bank won't post their name on Twitter!  A tech professional should be someone who guides their company into the best way forward.  If you can't or won't and want to support ancient software, then is it appropriate as current question?  Google dropped support for IE 9... want to tell them that that bank wants IE 6?

Comment: @JeremyMiller can you please focus on what the question is asking?

Comment: You've a proper DTD at the very beginning of the file? No preceding code or characters, not even blank characters or newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your Style will be working, as I think you have applied CSS in pixels, now please tell me how can a css be applied to a control which change it's position on enlarging it!! You need to use "%" instead of "px", pixels will make the things static, if I am applying CSS using my Laptop and I try to run the same application on my Desktop whose Screen is much wider than Lapi then how can things may work similarly on both the Screen's!! So, just try to apply CSS in % and not in px.